# Can I authenticate through a server side app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, intercom

Imagine that I have an Intercom style app (running on some-website.com). That is, a piece of code delivered by some-website.com which renders a popup chat which is ultimately populated by intercom-style-app.com. To see what I mean, go any website using intercom to see the chat pop up.

Imagine now that I want to be able to "log in" as a client-side user into that app. I go to intercom-style-app.com and log in -- I should now be recognized as logged in by any website which has the intercom-style-app.com code snippet running on their website.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sure?  Wouldn't be very secure though.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it wouldn't be secure?

Comment: My understanding is that you'd have to pass a token or something from the client side, which could be copied by another user, etc.

Comment: The way I'm reading this, you're wanting the client to do the authentication.  Which is in the users control.  And then the client tells the server, trust me?  Authentication should be done on the server.

Comment: Hmm, I moreso mean that the server would also be able to authenticate / recognize the user, does that make sense?

Comment: Not sure.  Can you perhaps provide more details in your question.  From your last paragraph it seems like you're saying you want to authenticate with website A, and have that authentication be recognized on website B.  Is this accurate?

Comment: No, I'll update to make it clearer.

Comment: Question has been updated to hopefully be clearer.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking whether intercom-app.com can store authentication state (ie a cookie) that is used by some-website.com which embeds content from intercom-app.com? So you've logged in once to intercom-app.com and then when the intercom widget loads on some-website.com, you're logged in already?

Comment: Correct, I think

Comment: Yes this is possible, provided that you want to be recognized as logged in by the intercom-style-app on the secondary site.  The app script on the page would have to make a request back to the source site, using a cookie that has the domain of the source site, which would be used to identify the user.  The cookies are scoped to the script site, not the site the script is ran on, so so long as the script properly makes the ajax requests allowing the cookies to be attached to the request, the ajax request will send the correct cookies to it.